# Mod_rewrite with constant parameter following the $1 variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to change via mod_rewrite the URL example.com/username/progress to example.com/username/?id=progress using the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/progress /$1/?id=progress [QSA]
```

Any ideas why it's returning a 500 error?

Comment: @user1796388 Sorry but I have a simple question, Are you sure mod_rewrite is enabled on your server? Also, an answer for Jon Lin question will help a lot.